# How do I fix an Error with pip install bllipparser?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, stanford-nlp, bllip-parser

I was trying to install the bllipparser for a project and used the command pip install bllipparser in the terminal, but I got the following error.

```
Installing collected packages: bllipparser
    Running setup.py install for bllipparser ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\1000284172\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aik213us\\bllipparser_736f2d4697234f66883f283f0d23bdcf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\1000284172\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aik213us\\bllipparser_736f2d4697234f66883f283f0d23bdcf\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dvw0bufb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\bllipparser'
         cwd: C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-aik213us\bllipparser_736f2d4697234f66883f283f0d23bdcf\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\CharniakParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\JohnsonReranker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\ModelFetcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\ParsingShell.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\RerankerFeatureCorpus.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\RerankingParser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\Utility.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    copying python\bllipparser\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\bllipparser
    running build_ext
    building 'bllipparser._CharniakParser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\1000284172\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aik213us\\bllipparser_736f2d4697234f66883f283f0d23bdcf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\1000284172\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-aik213us\\bllipparser_736f2d4697234f66883f283f0d23bdcf\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dvw0bufb\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\1000284172\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Include\bllipparser' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there any issue with the installation method? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to follow what is suggested in the error message? `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a compiler as your error states:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

However, even if you get that fixed, this package is not really compatible with windows, see [this github issue](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/issues/48). So you are probably better of switching to a different OS or a different package

Comment: Do you know any other package compatible with windows? Im using this for generating a parse tree for Grammar in python.

Comment: No, sorry. NLP is not my field of expertise.